# iOS accessibility labels not shown in Instruments on device build

Tags: ios, accessibility, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I have been putting accessibility labels into our source code so that we can automate using apples automation framework.  When we first started this project, we were building using sdk 4.3 and I had troubles getting the simulator to show the labels in the application.  Through advice on stack overflow I was able to fix it by altering the accessibility.plist in the simulator files.

Now that we have switched over to iOS sdk 5.0.  I am having the opposite problem.  I can no longer get the labels to show up on the device when I run our automation tests.  They show up fine in the simulator.  And I'm also able to confirm that they were properly compiled into the application by turning on VoiceOver on the device and doing a triple-double tab of and application window to show the elements.

I've looked over all the build settings and made sure everything was set to a debug build, and have tried going back to a build that I know worked when building for a 4.3 device and having the same exact settings(except for the sdk version of course) but the labels are still not being picked up.

So where do I go from here?  Is there a library file that needs to be included into the application when building for iOS 5?

Answer (score 2):

On the device, in "Settings > Accessibility > Triple-click Home", choose "Ask".  This seems to turn on "enough" of the accessibility machinery to make things work, but not so much of it that it'll interfere with the normal functions of the device (ex. turning on VoiceOver works too, but changes the flow of the app in ways that break tests.)